# How to make WCF set a connection string for use with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

Using EntityFramework, I have an auto-generated file with:

```
namespace Chaos.Data    
{
public partial class ChaosModel : OpenAccessContext, IChaosModelUnitOfWork
{
    private static string connectionStringName = @"ChaosLibraryConnection";

    private static BackendConfiguration backend = GetBackendConfiguration();

    private static MetadataSource metadataSource = XmlMetadataSource.FromAssemblyResource("EntitiesModel.rlinq");

    public ChaosModel()
        :base(connectionStringName, backend, metadataSource)
    { }

    public ChaosModel(string connection)
        :base(connection, backend, metadataSource)
    { }

     ......................
```

In the WCF Service, I am using:

```
namespace Chaos.DataService
{
[ServiceContract]
public class ChaosService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Encountertime> GetEncounterTimes(DateTime? encountertime)
    {
        if (encountertime == null) return null;

        using (var context = new ChaosModel())
        {
            var query = from et in context.Encountertimes
                        where et.Tencounter.Date == ((DateTime)encountertime).Date
                        select et;

           var result = context.CreateDetachedCopy(query.ToList());
            return result;
        }
    }
 .............................
```

How can I make the WCF service on startup execute a method (once) that will return a new connection string so that I can change the calls to ChaosModel() to:

```
using (var context = new ChaosModel(connectionString))
```

(I am looking for a way to add a static constructor within the WCF service--or something better?).

(The method will determine the network I am on and construct an appropriate connection string to the network server.)

Note: I can make no changes to the auto-generated Entity file.

Comment: Another option (in case I totally misread your question) would be to create the connection string and cache it - you could have the service do a check for the connection string in the cache and if it's not present create it and store it in the cache.

Comment: @Tim How do I have the service check for the connection string? I am confused on how to use the [OperationalContract] attributes???

Comment: Something like this in your code (this is probably not the most elegant solution):  `if (cache["ConnectionString"] == null) { // get the connection string, put it in cache } else { connectionString = (string)cache["ConnectionString"]) }`.  You can use `MemoryCache` as a caching mechanism if you're not using ASP.NET caching.

Comment: MemoryCache will do. (for simplicity, I used a static class with a static connection string in the Using block.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use static constructor.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class ChaosService 
{
    private static string connectionString;

    static ChaosService(){
        connectionString = your logic...
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Encountertime> GetEncounterTimes(DateTime? encountertime)
    {
        using (var context = new ChaosModel(connectionString))
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

or eventually a singleton pattern:

```
public class ConnectionInfo
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    private ConnectionInfo()
    {
        var connectionstring = string.Empty;
        //some logic

        this.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
    }

    private static ConnectionInfo current;

    public static ConnectionInfo Current {
        get {
            if (current != null)
                current = new ConnectionInfo();

            return current;
        }
    }
}        

[OperationContract]
public IEnumerable<Encountertime> GetEncounterTimes(DateTime? encountertime)
{
    using (var context = new ChaosModel(ConnectionInfo.Current.ConnectionString))
    {
       ...
    }
}
```